# laravel Greater than other field

Tags: php, laravel

I have the record package_id, it is a number field, so I want to check if its not empty or greater than 0 in controller, NOW this is working if package_id=2 in the database but if package_id is null then it will work exactly as if its equal 2 !!! why?? and how to check if only greater than 0 or not null

```
if(Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->where('package_id', 2)->count() > 1) {
     //do somthing... 
  }
```

Comment: try this may be it helps  ->where('package_id','>', 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$query = Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->where('package_id','>', 0)->count();
      if($query > 0){
        //do somthing...
      }else{
        //do somthing...
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$query = Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->where('package_id','>', 0)->get();
      if(!empty($query) && count($query) > 0){
        //Your output
      }else{
        //Your output
      }
```

Comment: I make a test and found that package_id is null and still redirect as if its not null